Mathematical Nominalism and Semantic Truth
I recently listened to a podcast with Jody Azzouni on the position of mathematical nominalism, a position I surprisingly have not considered until now. I have always struggled to found my conception of mathematical truth, wavering in and out of constructivism. I cannot commit myself to platonism, especially regarding Set Theory. In the end, I keep coming back to recognizing that it is just a formal game and that I have no way to conceive of what the set of real numbers actually is besides a syntactic object that enjoys certain syntactic properties.
Azzouni makes a criticism on the use and meaning of quantifiers noting that when referring to semantic truth, we are just pushing back the quantifiers into the meta-theory. For example, if we are using Tarski's truth predicate in model-theory, the quantifiers still exist inside the formal system ZFC. The nominalist perspective is that the use of quantifiers does not commit one to ontological existence of objects in which the formalism is referring to. However it is very useful to treat the objects as if they exist using language.
Furthermore, in this video by Kane B on abstract objects. He mentions the problem of concrete objects; the boundary we place on concrete objects are decided by the one perceiving or referencing the object. The existence of the object is not in the shared physical world, because it is always changing and its boundary is ambiguous, it is in the mind of the person naming the object as a concept. It serves a use to model the world as atomic objects and to quantify over them using language.
This comes to my question, ironically enough, does semantic truth mean anything? Where does it occur without being reducible to syntactic or formal truth?
I want to go through an example that I've been thinking about regarding quantifiers in a non-constructive result. It regards Gödel's Completeness theorem, which is non-constructive and thus not a result in the finitistic meta-theory of first order systems. The non-constructive step reduces to the uncomputablility of whether a sentence phi is provable from a set of axioms. It makes sense to state that phi is either is provable or not; it seems absurd to refute that. However, even that claim is not constructive because the existence of a finite algorithm for this purpose would contradict finite arithmetic. The way I conceived of any meaning of the Completeness Theorem, was the following. Given a computable enumeration of every sentence in the lexicon of my theory {phi_n}, there must exist an infinite countable sequence {P_n} of 0s and 1s such that P_n = 1 if and only if phi_n is provable. It feels intuitively true to say that out of every possible countable infinite sequence of 0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,...s there has to be one of the that corresponds exactly to when there is a proof of phi_n. The mental conception of which perhaps gives us credence as to assuming its existence may not lead to a contradiction. However, I am merely asserting its existence syntactically using language. The mental conception of its existence does not convince me that the object exists in some platonic manner. Especially since the very existence of an object is non-computable and is thus inaccessible by us finite beings. It all seems to collapse back on using quantifiers inside the language used to describe the meta-theory.
The platonist will rebut and ask even if you do not believe in the ontology of the natural number (for example), why do you have credence that PA is consistent (which is a claim that directly corresponds to whether a certain experience in our finite world is possible, namely observing a contradictory proof from PA). A response may be that belief in the consistency of PA follows from an appeal to induction, not the claim of existence of the natural numbers. One is able to conceive of the higher order concept of the set of natural numbers and intuit that they are cohesive; we can glimpse at the model in our mind without ever claiming that existence of the whole. Is this appeal to induction and the nominalist position compatible? Or is that appeal to induction inherently platonic?
Is nominalism correct? Would it be correct to say that nominalism is an interpretation of formalism? Does semantic truth only exist in finite models? That is if my model is {0,1,2,3} and P(x) is a predicate, then For all x, P(x) means P(0) and P(1) and P(2) and P(3).

Azzouni's nominalism could be seen as a possible consistent semantic interpretation of formalism who would argue that infinite models are merely linguistic constructs and their "truth" reduces to syntactic considerations about the rules governing those constructs. OTOH platonism doesn't necessarily need one's commitment to an independent realm so long as one commits to some objective mental persistence of math objects or invariance of structures, as Bernays suggested to complement purely game-semantic formalism. You can also view them as left/right adjoint functors without ontic conflict...

There are too many questions for a single post. Nominalism, or fictionalism as it is more commonly called now, is generally distinct from formalism, but Azzouni explicitly describes his position as a "version of formalism", see SEP, Contemporary Formalism. Semantic truth has literal meaning in paradigmatic discourses, with referents corresponding to reality as in empirical science. Nominal/fictional discourses are parasitic on them and useful when fictional objects share sufficiently many formal traits with literal objects.

You ask:

Is nominalism correct? Would it be correct to say that nominalism is an interpretation of formalism? Does semantic truth only exist in finite models?

In the game of worldviews, modern secular philosophical thinkers tend to lead towards teleological adequacy in lieu of correctness. With science, one might say, Newton was correct until he was made incorrect by Einstein, but then that begs the question what does it mean to have a "correct" worldview. Newton was adequate to predict, until GR showed cases where Newtonian space and time was inadequate, say with GPS satellites. Remember, in modern physicalism, my time is not "correct" and yours "incorrect" since there is no absolute frame of reference. The philosophy of mathematics has a similar analogy. But my frame might be more adequate for this or that purpose.
If you ask some modern thinkers, Plato was adequate until Frege's antipsychologism failed, and QM revealed that "correct" is contingent upon the observer. Is wave correct? Or is particle? Or is one or the other merely adequate under a specific set of empirical circumstances. (And the combined duality far more adequate than either alone.) Netwonian physics is less adequate than relativistic physics. Classical logic is less adequate than logical pluralism. And the belief that numbers have physical referents that are free of psychological abstraction of experience is less adequate than mathematical intuitionism, if you ask Brouwer and his defenders. Of course, neo-Platonists are a persistent bunch and will die on the hill that abstract objects (SEP) are in some sense real. I would encourage you to think about what linguistic formal semantics presumes about the gulf between the physical world and the mental one, and to ask yourself if mathematical realism is just confusing the map with the territory. If you find yourself saying yes, then perhaps fictionalism is simply more adequate that neo-Platonism.

I keep coming back to the matter of consistency in classical Peano arithmetic. This is a claim about what is possible in finite arithmetic, a realm that I'm sure no one disagrees in the existence of truth values for sentences. Is that correct? Does the consistency of first-order PA have a truth value? It is of the form There Exists x s.t. R(x) where R(x) is computable and represents x is a proof of a contraction. The belief that that statement is false and there doesn't exist such a proof can only be contingent on some sort of platonic conception of the natural numbers.

That is, if we hold that first order PA is consistent (a very real statement), are we committing ourselves to platonism for natural numbers? In this case, how is it up to us to decided which framework is adequate? We know that, if Con(PA), we will never prove Con(PA) finitistically. In this case, must one take the position the Con(PA) does not have a truth value and it is up to what framework you use in the meta-theory?

Let me review Gentzen's proof. My inclination as someone who rejects Actual Infinity is to highlight that the syntaxes of induction are the primary mechanism of metaphysical grounding , and therefore we don't concede Platonic of we understand infinite regress as a psychological grounding in a doxastic sense. But that's shooting from the hip. Make sense?

I also briefly recall Gentzen's proof and that transfinite induction up to epsilon_0 is required. Which as a set theorist I'm perfectly fine with, but as a philosopher I have trouble justifying, it feels like too far of a leap. I don't entirely understand what you are claiming we ought to hold when saying "we don't concede platonic if we understand infinite regress as a psychological grouping in a doxastic sense". I don't have a leap though on accepting ordinary induction. It seems like a leap that one has no justification to deny.

I realize I am now arguing for the perspective of platonism for natural numbers, but if one interprets for all x, P(x) as the promise that given any number x that you have constructed that P(x) and exists x, s.t. P(x) is the promise that if you starting counting from 0 and checking P you will eventually terminate at a number such that P(x). The leap from ~all x P(x) -> exists x ~P(x) is non-constructive, yes, but how can I reject it? If it is not the case any number you given me P(x) then I have the belief that if you start counting you will reach a number s.t. ~P(x).

Obviously these are mostly not accessibly to any finite mathematician and perhaps they will never be. But that is not what we are talking about when we use induction, no? Every number can be accessed in a finite amount of time. This is unlike the universe of sets, which I absolutely cannot hold platonism and maybe even plenitudinous platonism about. The inclusion of Power Set and Choice introduces "ghost sets", objects that can never be accessed or constructed; similarly with the reals. Is that not a valid distinction for credence of platonism, whether or not all referents can be accessed?

Or once again could this be also taken from a nominalist view where perhaps natural numbers don’t exist because we had to create them and the belief that sentences like the twin prime conjectures have a “truth value” can still exist without the commitment to the number’s ontology?

Okay after working through a couple examples I feel less convinced that every sentence in number theory has a truth value.

These are outstanding ruminations. I have to table this until the weekend, but I will follow-up one way or another bc articulating a response will scratch an itch I've had for awhile in thinking about constructivism, potential infinity, and pscyhologistic basis for mathematics. (Embodied cognition figures prominently in my philosophy of mathematics.) Thanks for the stimulating question.

Of course. I would love to write up some of what I worked out the other day. I was essentially framing quantifiers as a game between for all and exists. Where each player iterates through the natural numbers according to some rules and the truth value is determined by the game terminating or not. But as soon as you have at least two alternating quantifiers, you cannot build a computable algorithm whose termination status will coincide with the truth value; both true and false will not terminate. The deciding factor then is whether it …

… will get locked in a state after some point in time and “never deviate” or if at any point in time it will reach a new state eventually. These conditions are harder to accept as someone who does not accept actual infinity than a computer program terminating or not (although that is still a leap).

It comes down to the belief that “every possible countably infinite sequence of 0 or 1 exists”. Which doesn’t mean something tangible. But I still derive meaning with it by some pseudo modal thought experiment. Imagine a random oracle that spits out a digit 0 or 1 every second (and ignore the heat death of the universe etc.). Then there is a possible world where the first digit is 0 and one that is 1. Then for any sequence with any property this is a possible world where the oracle will produce every digit in that sequence.

Emphasis on will because this is still not actual infinity. At any point in time the sequence that has been produced looks like it should be correct. And we know that in some possible world it will never not be correct at any time. Once again we are just pushing back belief to random oracles and possible worlds meaning anything.

I don't think we're pushing belief to possible worlds at all. I think that the Infinity and PW syntax is a syntactical primitive in and of itself and what the power of the notation is that we can treat generative methods of syntax, like a potentially infinite string, as a WFF that has semantics by leaning on the form of induction as a form of semantic grounding. I think that's why ordinals and transfinite induction is acceptable in the first place, because both are semantically deductive forms grammatically speaking. In my view, the question is doxastic and not epistemic bc dealing w regress..

I'll write up some thoughts on Sunday myself.


"Would it be correct to say that nominalism is an interpretation of formalism?"

Abraham Robinson's take on this was to agree with nominalists with regard to infinite sets, namely that the latter have no reference (in either the physical or any putative Platonic realm), but to disagree with them with regard to things like "a set of five chairs" and similar things, which can be grasped in full detail without a need to insist on the irreality of such sets and the primality of the individual entity.
The idea about the approach being "just a formal game" is not intrinsic to Formalism, but only to a certain caricature of Formalism.  Here is an interesting comment Simpson made about Hilbert in 1986:

"With hindsight, we can see that Hilbert's proposal in step 2.2 to
view infinitistic formulas as meaningless led to an unnecessary
intellectual disaster. Namely, it left Hilbert wide open to Brouwer's
accusation of 'empty formalism.' Brouwer's accusation was clearly
without merit. A balanced reading shows that Hilbert's overall
intention was not to divest infinitistic formulas of meaning, but
rather to invest them with meaning by reference to finitistic
mathematics, the meaning of which is unproblematic. Nevertheless, this
part of Hilbert's formulation was confusing and made it easy for
Brouwer to step in and pin Hilbert with a false label. The whole drama
had the bad effect of lending undeserved respectability to empty
formalism. We are still paying the price of Hilbert's rhetorical
flourish."

In sum, one can reject Platonism's unwarranted assumptions without falling into the other extreme of nominalism.

In that quote, what is the meaning of "...but rather invest them with meaning by reference to finitistic mathematics..."? Is the "finitistic" referring to the meta-theory being finitistic? Or that the logical rules being used in classical logic are justified through intuition of finite sets? Or neither of the two (obviously).

A good example is provided by the results in reverse mathematics which entail the conservativity of WKL_0 over PRA for Pi^0_2 sentences.  This shows that, for example, the Hahn-Banach theorem (in a suitable setting) does not risk leading to a contradiction any more than PRA does.  Note that PRA is generally thought to be finitistic.  To a Formalist, such a relative proof of non-contradiction is a satisfactory result.
